# MAMP + Rails MYSQL installation issue. Can't create a rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mamp

I have had no luck getting a new rails app up and running while using MAMP on Yosemite.

```
user$ rails new testrailsapp -d mysql --with-mysqlconfig=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.21/bin/mysql_config
       exist  
   identical  README.rdoc
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  config.ru
   identical  .gitignore
   identical  Gemfile
       exist  app
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
   identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
   identical  app/assets/images/.keep
   identical  app/mailers/.keep
   identical  app/models/.keep
   identical  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
   identical  app/models/concerns/.keep
       exist  bin
   identical  bin/bundle
   identical  bin/rails
   identical  bin/rake
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
    conflict  config/secrets.yml
Overwrite /Users/user/testrailsapp/config/secrets.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] a
       force  config/secrets.yml
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/assets.rb
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
   identical  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
   identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  config/boot.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
       exist  db
   identical  db/seeds.rb
       exist  lib
       exist  lib/tasks
   identical  lib/tasks/.keep
       exist  lib/assets
   identical  lib/assets/.keep
       exist  log
   identical  log/.keep
       exist  public
   identical  public/404.html
   identical  public/422.html
   identical  public/500.html
   identical  public/favicon.ico
   identical  public/robots.txt
       exist  test/fixtures
   identical  test/fixtures/.keep
       exist  test/controllers
   identical  test/controllers/.keep
       exist  test/mailers
   identical  test/mailers/.keep
       exist  test/models
   identical  test/models/.keep
       exist  test/helpers
   identical  test/helpers/.keep
       exist  test/integration
   identical  test/integration/.keep
   identical  test/test_helper.rb
       exist  tmp/cache
       exist  tmp/cache/assets
       exist  vendor/assets/javascripts
   identical  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
       exist  vendor/assets/stylesheets
   identical  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.4.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.7
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.7
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.1.7
Using mime-types 2.4.3
Using mail 2.6.1
Using actionmailer 4.1.7
Using activemodel 4.1.7
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.7
Using bundler 1.7.4
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.2.2
Using coffee-script 2.3.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.7
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.4
Using jquery-rails 3.1.2

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141101-36276-1x98hhg.rb extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/mysql2-0.3.16/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling.
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

.

.When I attempt to run the mysql2 install, I get this:

```
users-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141101-37298-dtpq0m.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0/mysql2-0.3.16/gem_make.out
```

.

.my /etc/paths looks like this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

.
.
.
mysql status
UNIX socket:        /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

.
.
.
I also tried:

```
rails new testrailsapp -d mysql –-with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
```

.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you type `mysql -u root -p` in the terminal, and see if your mysql works.

Comment: `Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.5.38 Source distribution
Server version:  5.5.38 Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
Connection:  Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset: latin1
Db     characterset: latin1
Client characterset: utf8
Conn.  characterset: utf8
UNIX socket:  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: Have you tried `brew install mysql`? MAMP can be a PITA since it installs all the libs & binaries inside `/Applications/mamp`. I would recommend [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) or if you must use MySQL installing it with homebrew and using another app (if needed) to turn it on / off.

Comment: It sure is a PITA!

`users-MacBook-Pro:mysql user$ brew install mysql
Warning: mysql-5.6.21 already installed
`

Comment: well, i guess that your mysql is installed correctly, now what i would like to do if i had a linux system was 
`sudo nano /etc/path` and add `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin` and then try just `rails new testrailsapp -d mysql`

Comment: See the bottom of my original post. /etc/path already has that top line.

Same failure, essentially.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141101-6597-15s48q8.rb extconf.rb 
...removed some stuff to allow comment length..
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
-----
mysql.h is missing.  please check your installation of mysql and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: http://ionrails.com/2011/04/13/bundle-install-missing-mysql-h/

Comment: try 
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev  #(mysql development headers)
sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/etc/mysql/
thats how i got my extconf.rb error resolved. but i was on linux

Comment: that won't fly in my terminal (apt-get).